# Most of the dishes ( in / of / at ) the student cafeteria are not good

Tags: word-usage

> Most of the dishes ( in / of / at ) the student cafeteria are not good.

Here, I feel '**at**' and '**in**' are more suitable when there's a verb. So I think '**of**' is the most suitable here. which one is the best here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the message you want to convey.

Use 'in' if you refer to the dishes within the student cafeteria.

Use 'at' if you refer to the dishes located at a specific area in the student cafeteria (i.e. at the entrance, at this specific stall in the student cafeteria).

Use 'of' if you want to specify that the student cafeteria (**as an entity**) doesn't produce good food/dishes.

Comment: Or *at* the cafeteria as opposed to somewhere else, such as *at home*.

Comment: Except that "of" in this case would sound extremely odd. The **most** likely would be "in".